# How to setup TeamCity with LDAP sync when FQDN uses national charset in OU naming (cirillic)?

Tags: ldap, teamcity

Looks like this post  [How to setup TeamCity with LDAP group membership synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57968584/how-to-setup-teamcity-with-ldap-group-membership-synchronization)

Our OU contains national charset + spaces in naming (pls don`t ask "why")
I can bind user to AD with only name, without FQDN, but cannot map user or groups.
for example:
in ldap-config.properties:
teamcity.users.base=OU=Свои Люди,OU=Офис
and
in ldap-mapping.xml -
group-mapping teamcityGroupKey="support" ldapGroupDn="CN=admins,OU=Нашсаппорт,OU=Офис,DC=intra,DC=net"/>

At LDAPsync page i`ve got error -
Used search base: 'OU=ÐÑÐ´Ð¸,OU=Ð¦ÐµÐ½ÑÑÐ°Ð»ÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ ÐÑÐ¸Ñ' (set by 'teamcity.users.base' property, should be relative to the value of 'java.naming.provider.url') ...
LDAP: error code 32 - 0000208D: NameErr: DSID-03100238, problem 2001 (NO_OBJECT)

Probably I must encode Cyrillic names in config files?
In TC interface i can edit and see right encoding.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem using UTF-16 code like

> config.properties: teamcity.users.base=OU=\u0421\u0432\u043e\u0438 \u041b\u044e\u0434\u0438,OU=\u041e\u0444\u0438\u0441

instead of unicode text

> teamcity.users.base=OU=Свои Люди,OU=Офис

You can convert your text simply on https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter and copy and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

I think its done.  I set config.properties: teamcity.users.base exactly as is in  `Get-ADGroup ourgroup -Properties **DistinguishedName**`, then save ldap-mapping.xml UTF8 without BOM encoding and ldap-config.properties as ASCII. Then I can sync TC users from AD.